# Sorting array of Struct items depending on the name

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

I wish someone can help me. I'm new at programming and my problem is this, I'm trying to alphabetically sort different **struct** items depending on which one is the first letter of the name entered in that **struct** item. I tried different things but I'm stuck in here.

I pasted here the code I wrote. I commented the part that I help on, and since I need the program to be in spanish, some parts of my code are in this language. I hope that's not a problem for understanding what I'm trying to do.

PD. If you guys would have some advises for me to improve my skills, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXNOMBRE 15
#define MAXAPELLIDO 15
#define MAXDIRECCION 30
#define MAXTEL 12
#define MAXALUMNOS 4


struct Alumno
{
    char nombre[MAXNOMBRE];
    char apellido[MAXAPELLIDO];
    char direccion[MAXDIRECCION];
    int edad;
    char telefono[MAXTEL];
} alumnos[MAXALUMNOS], alumnos_cpy[1]; 

int main()
{
    int contador=0, i=0, j=0, k;
    char seleccion;


    system("CLS");

    do
    {
        printf("BIENVENIDO AL REGISTRO\n");
        printf("a) Registrar alumno\n");
        printf("b) Mostrar alumnos\n");
        printf("c) Salir\n");
        scanf("%s", &seleccion);

        switch (seleccion)
        {
            case 'A': case 'a':
                if (contador < MAXALUMNOS)
                {   
                    printf("Lugares Disponibles: <%d>\n", MAXALUMNOS-contador);
                    printf("Numero de alumnos que desee registrar: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%d", &j);

                    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");

                        printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        gets(alumnos[contador].nombre);
                        printf("Ingrese el apellido del alumno: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        gets(alumnos[contador].apellido);
                        printf("Ingrese direccion (calle y numero): ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        gets(alumnos[contador].direccion);
                        printf("Ingrese edad: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d", &alumnos[contador].edad);
                        printf("Ingrese telefono: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        gets(alumnos[contador].telefono);
                        contador++;

                        printf("\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("La memoria ya esta llena!\n");
                }

                //ALPHABETICALLY SORTING
                //ALPHABETICALLY SORTING
                //ALPHABETICALLY SORTING
                for (i = 0; i <= contador-1; i++)
                {   
                    if (alumnos[i].nombre[0] > alumnos[i+1].nombre[0])
                    {

                        // memcpy(&alumnos_cpy[0], &alumnos[i], sizeof(alumnos[i]));
                        // memcpy(&alumnos[i], &alumnos[i+1], sizeof(alumnos[i+1]));
                        // memcpy(&alumnos[i+1], &alumnos_cpy[0], sizeof(alumnos_cpy[0]));
                        // //alumnos_cpy[0] = alumnos[i];
                        // //alumnos[i] = alumnos[i+1];
                        // //alumnos[i+1] = alumnos_cpy[0];
                    }
                }
                //ALPHABETICALLY SORTING
                //ALPHABETICALLY SORTING
                //ALPHABETICALLY SORTING


                printf("\nPresione Enter para continuar...");
                break;


            case 'B': case 'b':
                for (i = 0; i < contador; i++)
                {
                    printf("\n\nAlumno %d", i+1);
                    printf("\nNombre: %s %s", alumnos[i].nombre, alumnos[i].apellido);
                    printf("\nDireccion: %s", alumnos[i].direccion);
                    printf("\nEdad: %d", alumnos[i].edad);
                    printf("\nTelefono: %s", alumnos[i].telefono);
                }

                printf("\nPresione Enter para continuar...");
                break;

            case 'C': case 'c':
                printf("Presione Enter para salir...");
                break;

            default:
                printf("Seleccion Incorrecta - Intente de Nuevo\n");
                printf("Presione Enter para continuar...");
                break;

        }

        getch();
        system("CLS");

    } while (seleccion != 'C' && seleccion != 'c');


    printf("\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually copying the entire struct, you could use `qsort` to do the work for you. You would simply write a helper function that returns -1, 0 or 1. The `qsort` function will do the rest of the logic.

```
// qsort helper function
int alumno_sort(void *p1, void *p2) {
    struct Alumno *a1 = p1, *a2 = p2;
    return strcasecmp(a1->nombre, a2->nombre);
}

// actually sorting
qsort(alumnos, contador, sizeof *alumnos, alumno_sort);
```

Another way to approach this, is to put your structs in e.g. a linked list instead of an array. Then you could swap around the references to the other items to sort the list.